# Avoid uploading file again on returning to page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, viewstate

An ASP.NET MVC page has some text fields, some drop down fields and a file upload bar. I uploaded a file through the browse bar, submit the form and navigate to another page. Now, on coming back to this page, I see that all the fields except the file upload bar have their entered/selected values retained EXCEPT the uploaded file in the file upload bar.

(I use Angular JS.)

How to retain the uploaded file in the upload bar, so I need not browse and upload it again? (store it to viewstate?/ on mapping it to the model, how to save a '.csv file' type in it?)

Comment: You cannot. For security reasons, the value of a file input can only be set by the users selecting a file in their browser (and in any case if it were set then it would be uploaded again). You can just display the name of the file to indicate to the user what has already been uploaded.

Comment: (Speaking to the angularjs side) Properties on service or factory objects persist while the app is running, regarding saving the file data it's basically a big string, so long as you can read the data you should be able to temporarily store it (assuming here by navigating to another view you mean using a client side router and .net mvc is just being used as a REST API, if full page refreshes then all injected services etc. are recreated, normal client side routing only destroys and creates controller instances)